# Unable to get data through HttpGet in android

Tags: android, json, cakephp

I am trying to send data using the following url but Its somehow being declared invalid query in Logcat

```
Base_URI/users/add.json?json={“email”: xxx@x.com, “password”: “xxxxxxxxx”, “first_name”: “Xyz”, “last_name”: “Xyz”}
```

I have asked this question before but found no solution so I am being more specific now.

The web services are made in cakephp as far as I know. Its not accepting url because of this part "json={}". Also the parameters are separated by ',' rather than '&'. In short, what encoding should I use to get json from it ?

I get this error in Logcat:

```
Illegal character in query at index 56
```

one more thing, No suggestions for third party library unless there is no solution in `org.apache.http` . By the way I tried Volley Library but had no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after debugging and trying different solutions the whole day, I solved my own problem :)

I needed to encode the parameters part and not the whole URL like this:

```
String url = "Base_URI/users/add.json?json=";
    url =url +  URLEncoder.encode("{\"email\":\""+email+"\",\"password\":\""+password+"\"}", "UTF-8");
```

Thanks everyone for taking part in it !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Base_URI/users/add.json?json={"email": "xxx@x.com", "password": "xxxxxxxxx","first_name": "Xyz", "last_name": "Xyz"}
```

Comment: Actually its not about quotation marks. I know I have written them wrong above. The problem is something else